# How is possible reading analog input and logging the data to SD card for this STM32 board?

Tags: stm32, arm

I'm very beginner in STM32. I have [STM32F746G](https://www.st.com/resource/en/data_brief/32f746gdiscovery.pdf) discovery board. This board has microSD slot. I want to read three analog channels and log these voltage data into the SD card. I'm not able to find any example or hint how are analog inputs read and logged to SD card. I have been looking for the entire day I couldn't find a single example tutorial or anything close.

Does anyone have any experience with such task?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seeks to find examples and is too broad in seeking the entire project.  Stack exchange sites are for narrow technical questions not help in finding resources or entire project solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read your analog inputs with the ADC module, converting your analog signal to digital data.

Then to communicate with the microSD and to log those digital data into the card, you need to use the SDMMC module.

You can find example codes in the h STM32CubeF7 MCU Package . 
https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef7.html
https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/47/af/1e/94/ef/a2/49/e6/DM00180213.pdf/files/DM00180213.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00180213.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the input. Im looking for any input or link or example Im desperate, but there is not a single example where I can see the functions. Im not expert but thanks anyway maybe SDMMC  explains everything I dont know.

Comment: But I cannot see any code in that pdf you linked:(

Comment: the code is not in the pdf, you have to install the mcu package which will provide you example codes

Comment: I now downloaded that. There is a folder called ADC under the Examples folder. But cannot find SD realted one. Which folder could be related to SD? The folders are under: STM32Cube_FW_F7_V1.15.0\Projects\STM32746G-Discovery\Examples

Comment: I don't know. Send a screen of your folder .

Comment: Dear @cm64, I think your expectations are too high. Prepare to spend a looong time to get this working. I have 30 year experience and it took me 3 weeks to get an SD-card more or less working. Also be warned that some SD-card types just don't work.  Build one part at a time and because the SD-card is the most difficult part, save that till the end when you have more experience.

Comment: I have found this: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/83/72/1e/52/2b/de/4c/7e/DM00210367.pdf/files/DM00210367.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00210367.pdf .

Check the FatFs and LibJPEG examples, they are using SD cards.

Comment: @Oldfart I see, I have a friend who is not an EE but a mechanical engineer he managed to log data using Arduino to an SD card. Do you think the challenge is due to STM32 ARM uC?

Comment: Yes. Arduino is much more simple.

Comment: Arduino has pre-made libraries to do stuff. ST has pre-made examples and HAL libraries for peripherals and FAT filesystem driver to start doing stuff. I expect it is not going to be a huge job combining two examples, one that reads ADC values and another that writes files to SD card.

Comment: ... the point really seems to be that cm64 assumes there's a "ready to go ADC-to-SD" example, and that's probably not the case. This is a software development process that cm64 needs to undergo.

Comment: In addition to @Wheatley's answer, for the SD card, you can use CubeMX to generate some code for interfacing with an SD card. Remember that SD cards can tend to get tricky. You can refer to [this github repository for an example](https://github.com/eziya/STM32_SPI_SDCARD)

Comment: CubeMX can generate most of the code. Getting it to work will take several days. But if you have specific requirements, it may take weeks, because libraries aren't flexible enough, and you basically need to rewrite them.